When generating a RESX file and adding resources to it, an exception occurs
I am doing a project of MS tests. There was a need to upload text files with test datasets to it. After creating a resx file and adding a resource to it, an error occurs when trying to access it through the generated class
An example of accessing a resource:
var file = Resources.Test;
Exception text:
System.MissingMethodException: "Constructor on type 'System.Byte[]' not found."
I tried to change the type of the "custom tool" generator, but another exception was raised, I tried to load other types of resources, but the problem is the same.

Update: the solution turned out to be simple. This is due to a Visual Studio bug, namely the new resource explorer. If you encounter a similar problem, just update the Visual Studio
